# How can we decide whether to use ZonedDateTime or LocalDateTime?

Tags: java

Sometimes, we find it is difficult to make judgement, whether to use `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`, when we want to solve certain date/ time problem.

For instance, given an epoch, we would like to know the day of the week.

We find we can accomplish this task, with either `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`. Here's the code example

```
import java.time.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Yield correct result.
        System.out.println("useLocalDateTime -> " + useLocalDateTime(currentTimeMillis));

        // Also yield correct result.
        System.out.println("useZonedDateTime -> " + useZonedDateTime(currentTimeMillis));
    }

    public static DayOfWeek useLocalDateTime(long currentTimeMillis) {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(currentTimeMillis),
                ZoneId.systemDefault()
        );

        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = localDateTime.getDayOfWeek();

        return dayOfWeek;
    }

    public static DayOfWeek useZonedDateTime(long currentTimeMillis) {
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(currentTimeMillis).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = zonedDateTime.getDayOfWeek();

        return dayOfWeek;
    }
}
```

---

In the above case, is it better to use `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`? Is there any guideline, so that we can pick up the correct class as tool?

I always have the impression that `ZonedDateTime` is more "feature rich" than `LocalDateTime`. Whatever can be accomplished by `LocalDateTime`, it can be accomplished by `ZonedDateTime` too, but not vice-versa. Hence, if I get stuck on which to choose, I will go to `ZonedDateTime` as default. Is that a correct concept?

Comment: Well, one thing you should consider, is whether you really need a timezone. If I were to display a small graphical calendar to the user, and I wanted to highlight the current day, I would pick `LocalDateTime`. It's irrelevant for the user in which zone he is, he just want the shown date to match his wall clock time. In other cases you may want to include timezones to adjust for e.g. dst.

Comment: @MCEmperor I always have an impression where `ZonedDateTime` is more "feature rich" than `LocalDateTime`. Is there any harm, if I just use `ZonedDateTime` consistently in my app?

Comment: There is absolutely no harm, and certainly not if you use it consistently.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to store time data that is attached to a specific time zone, or do you need to process time data that has an associated offset?

If you *do*, use `ZonedDateTime`.

If you *don't*, use `LocalDateTime`.

Some examples of when I would want to use `ZonedDateTime`:

- I'm parsing an ISO 8601 timestamp with zone information.
- I'm looking at data from two different sources located in two physically different locations.
- I'm trying to calculate what the day of the week is given a timestamp.

Some examples of when I would want to use `LocalDateTime`:

- I'm assured that my system only needs to care about one time zone - mine.
- The data that I'm parsing does not have time stamp information.
- I want to know how many seconds have passed between two time stamps.  This *may* get converted to a `ZonedDateTime` first before it eventualy decants into a `Duration` if the time stamps are in ISO 8601 format.

***Definitely*** be careful about days of the week across time zones, since the International Date Line can offset the day of the week depending on where you are physically located.

Comment: I always have an impression where ZonedDateTime is more "feature rich" than LocalDateTime. Is there any harm, if I just use ZonedDateTime consistently in my app? –

Comment: It's not about feature richness, they model different concepts. A `LocalDateTime` represents an abstract date-time, like "May 27th, 2020 17:13:36". But without a time-zone we can't map that abstract date-time to a moment-in-time; that's what a `ZonedDateTime` represents. It's a `LocalDateTime`+`ZoneId`.

Comment: Dimo is right here @CheokYanCheng.  You don't need to use `ZonedDateTime` unless you need to deal with a timezone.  `Duration`s don't need to care about time zones since they only hold information about a specific duration of time, and the duration of time is independent of where that time is represented.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `System.currentTimeMillis()` use [`ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) or [`Instant.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--). You should almost never need `currentTimeMillis()` in modern Java. Use the dedicated `java.time` APIs throughout your application, so that you're working with well-typed data structures instead of primitives like `long currentTimeMillis`.

---

> given an epoch, we would like to know the day of the week

It's worth recognizing that this isn't a meaningful question without a time zone; at any moment in time there are two (or more?) days of the week in different places on earth. So before we go further we need to ask *which* time zone(s) do you care about?

Generally speaking, the `systemDefault()` time zone is *not* what you want. Instead the caller should provide the time zone they expect. If your program is running locally and only ever needs your machine's clock it may be fine, but the very reason for the split between `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` is because the system is very often not the correct time zone to be using.

For trivial cases, e.g. a Java process running on your local machine that doesn't care about time zone changes over time, you *might* correctly use the system time zone. But in such cases it's a good idea to query the system near your `main()` method and then pass that zone through your application. This makes the application more scalable and testable, if the system zone stops being the right approach down the road.